# Ion-alpha-scroll with alpha scrollbar draggable/swip in Ionic

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I have tried an example using ion-alpha-scroll it is working fine, but I need to change one thing. [Here](http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.3.1a/built-examples/kitchensink/index.html#demo/groupedlist) is what I want to have.

When I drag/swipe the alphabets the list is scrolled to the selected item. How can I achieve this in Ionic?

Comment: Have you gotten anywhere with this?

Comment: @Stoopkid: Yes, I got it. I made some workout on the plugin and then I was able to get that functionality.

Comment: @bbsk can you share what changes you made? I need the same thing.

Comment: @yogurt: Sorry for my delay in reply. But hope this might be useful for someone else. I have used AlphaNav plugin.The link for this is https://github.com/tariq86/AlphaNav